# Excel VBA Hiding Rows

Tags: excel, vba

In the picture below, I'm trying to hide the rows that are empty in a certain cells (e.g. Row 39 to Row 48). Is is possible to do it in one click? I'm planning of doing it with VBA.

[image]

This is the formula that I'm currently using but the thing is the cells that I want to hide may not start at row 39 or ends at row 48, it depends on the data.

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("NAMES", "AUGUST"))
        'ws.Rows("39:48").Hidden = True
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @braX oh I'm sorry. I'll try to revise the question.

Comment: What are the limits of the range where you want to hide empty cells?

Comment: @TimWilliams empty cells at column C should be all hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hide 'Empty' Rows

- This is a slightly different approach:

  - uses `Option Explicit`
  - uses constants and variables
  - uses `For Each...Next` loops for both, worksheets and cells
  - qualifies all objects (e.g. `ws.Cells or rg.Cells`, not just `Cells`)
  - combines empty cells into a range
  - unhides all rows in one go, then hides the 'empty' rows in another (go)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HideRows()

    Const StartRow As Long = 9
    Const EndRow As Long = 89
    Const ColNum As Long = 3
    Dim WorksheetNames As Variant
    WorksheetNames = Array("NAMES", "AUGUST") ' add more
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet ' Current Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range ' Current Range
    Dim hrg As Range ' Current Hide Range
    Dim cCell As Range ' Current Cell in Range
    
    ' Loop through the worksheets in the workbook containing this code.
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WorksheetNames)
        ' Create a reference to the range of the current worksheet.
        Set rg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(StartRow, ColNum), ws.Cells(EndRow, ColNum))
        ' or using resize:
        'Set rg = ws.Cells(StartRow, ColNum).Resize(EndRow - StartRow + 1)
        ' Loop through the cells of the current range.
        For Each cCell In rg.Cells
            If IsEmpty(cCell) Then ' cell is empty
                ' Combine ('add') the current cell into the hide range.
                If Not hrg Is Nothing Then ' for all except the first
                    Set hrg = Union(hrg, cCell)
                Else ' for the first
                    Set hrg = cCell
                End If
            'Else ' cell is not empty - do nothing
            End If
        Next cCell
        ' Unhide all rows of the current range of the current worksheet.
        rg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If Not hrg Is Nothing Then ' there are combined cells
            ' Hide the rows of the hide range.
            hrg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ' Reset the hide range variable for the next worksheet.
            ' Also, note that 'Union' works only with ranges from one worksheet.
            Set hrg = Nothing
        'Else ' there are no combined cells - do nothing
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using your code above however it only works in the NAMES sheet and not with the other sheets.

Comment: Still working correctly on my end. Which other worksheets? You need to add their names to the array. The code has only `Names` and `August`. If you add a non-existing name, the code will fail.

Comment: I delete the other worksheets and only have the NAMES and AUGUST sheets but it only works on my NAMES sheet and not with the AUGUST sheet.

Comment: Is sheet AUGUST protected? Do you have merged cells? Is your data filtered? It works when the sheet is hidden.

Comment: I figured it out. There's no error with your code. I think the problem is because my AUGUST sheet has a formula `=IF(NAMES!C75="","",NAMES!C75)` which copy the data from the NAMES data.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Did you modify any lines in the code?

Comment: No. I just copy and paste your code.

Comment: But to make it work with my AUGUST sheet, I changed the `If IsEmpty(cCell) Then` line to `If cCell = "" Then`.

Comment: Got it. If the formula evaluating to "", it means that the cell is blank, but not empty. So we will modify the `If` statement. Try  `If Len(Cstr(cCell.Value)) > 0 Then`. Yours is also an option although mine is safer i.e. if there is an error value it won't fail. Test it by putting `=1/0` into a cell.

Comment: Noted with this. I'll use your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I already made it. Below is the script that I used.

```
Sub HideRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("NAMES", "AUGUST"))
    
        StartRow = 9
        EndRow = 89
        ColNum = 3
    
        For i = StartRow To EndRow
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, ColNum).Value) Then
                ws.Cells(i, ColNum).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                ws.Cells(i, ColNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next i
    
    Next
End Sub
```